# Identify median of a variable where consecutive 0’s arrive in a different variable

Tags: r

Below is how my data looks like.

```
 Group, Sales,flag,Count
Paris,6738,0,15
Paris,5235,1,23
Paris,5907,1,15
Paris,5527,0,28
Paris,6934,1,27
Paris,6757,0,20
Paris,5394,1,31
Paris,5379,0,36
Paris,6266,1,40
Paris,5512,1,39
Paris,6506,1,29
Paris,5006,1,22
Paris,6465,1,17
Paris,6653,0,38
Paris,6719,0,12
New York,5333,1,19
New York,6763,1,37
New York,6468,0,32
New York,6923,0,34
New York,6705,0,16
New York,6542,0,11
New York,6497,0,19
New York,6616,0,27
New York,6788,0,26
New York,5876,1,33
New York,5382,0,40
New York,5688,0,34
New York,6667,1,20
New York,5929,1,28
New York,6096,0,30
```

For each city, I would like to calculate the median sales for consecutive zeros that lie before and after flag “1”, for each city.

Below is the output i am getting after using the below code, suggested in the comments.

```
setDT(c)[, .(median(Sales), median(Count)), .(City, rleid(flag))][rleid %% 2 == 1, .(City, median = V1, count = V2)]
```

and below is the output the i am getting after using the suggested code.

```
head(d,20)
    City  median   count
1: Paris 6738.000 15.00000
2: Paris 5527.000 28.00000
3: Paris 6757.000 20.00000
4: Paris 5379.000 36.00000
5: Paris 6686.000 25.00000
6:    NY 6648.429 23.57143
7:    NY 5535.000 37.00000
8:    NY 6096.000 30.00000
```

The Expected output has been attached below.
The discrepancy is coming for NY group,(Median for Sales and Count)

**R Code output result:** 
6. NY - 6648.429 and Count - 23.57

**Excel output result:**
NY - 6616 and Count - 26

[image]

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rleid` from `data.table` to calculate mean per `City` and `rle` group (0s and 1s), then select where `group == 0`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(mean(Sales), mean(Count)), .(City, rleid(flag))][rleid %% 2 == 1, .(City, average = V1, count = V2)]

    City  average
1: Paris 4000.000
2: Paris 3833.333
3:    NY 4500.000
4:    NY 3500.000
```

`data[, rleid(flag)]` output is:
 `[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8`

Comment: Thanks! It worked... it there also a way to capture the "Count" value as well in the code.. i just updated the dataset.

Comment: @Jay I edited my code. It's easy, just add `.(mean(Sales), mean(Count))`

Comment: Hi, I want to capture the count value for the mean(sales) that we have captured in the initial code..

Comment: @jay please post wanted output

Comment: Sorry... just realised its not working for few cases... the output is different. It is considering flag==1 as recurring cases in the output.

Comment: I have updated the question with code results and expected result. The discrepancy is coming for NY group.

Comment: @jay have you tried replacing `mean` with `median`?

Comment: yes.. i did.. but it didn't work. The rbind code provided by r2evans worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

## Base-R

```
x <- read.csv(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
City, Sales, flag
Paris, 3000, 0
Paris, 4000, 0
Paris, 5000, 0
Paris, 3000, 1
Paris, 3000, 0
Paris, 4000, 0
Paris, 4500, 0
NY, 3000, 1
NY, 4000, 0
NY, 5000, 0
NY, 3000, 1
NY, 3000, 0
NY, 4000, 0
NY, 4500, 1')

do.call(rbind,
        by(x, list(x$City, cumsum(c(0,diff(x$flag)!=0))),
           function(a) { a$Sales <- mean(a$Sales) ; a[1,,drop=FALSE] ; }))
#     City    Sales flag
# 1  Paris 4000.000    0
# 4  Paris 3000.000    1
# 5  Paris 3833.333    0
# 8     NY 3000.000    1
# 9     NY 4500.000    0
# 11    NY 3000.000    1
# 12    NY 3500.000    0
# 14    NY 4500.000    1
```

## `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  mutate(flaggroup = cumsum(c(0,diff(flag)!=0))) %>%
  group_by(City, flaggroup) %>%
  summarize(Sales = mean(Sales), flag = first(flag)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-flaggroup)
# # A tibble: 8 × 3
#    City    Sales  flag
#   <chr>    <dbl> <int>
# 1    NY 3000.000     1
# 2    NY 4500.000     0
# 3    NY 3000.000     1
# 4    NY 3500.000     0
# 5    NY 4500.000     1
# 6 Paris 4000.000     0
# 7 Paris 3000.000     1
# 8 Paris 3833.333     0
```

Comment: I tried your code. I am getting the same error.It's not working for one group correctly.
R Code output result: 6. NY - 6648.429 and Count - 23.57

Excel output result: NY - 6616 and Count - 26

Please check my initial post.

Comment: Of course you'll get different answers there ... when I answered the question, you were asking for the *average*. Now you're asking for the *median* (and also changed all of your data). If you replace `mean` with `median` in my code, that NY row gives you 6616.

Comment: Jay, are you still getting an error? If not an error, are you getting differences in calculations that can be attributed to something other than `median`-vs-`mean`?

Comment: Hi R2evans, it’s workint fine. I just had a question, is there a way to capture the corresponding count value for each median sales in the output as well. The current code provides by you helps to capture a median or mean for count, but what if there is a way to capture the corresponding values from the initial data as well at the same time. The only challenge I see would be the number of observations. For odd it would work fine, but for even it needs to take the average of count, and provide the result. Not sure how it can be done, however seeking your expertise for the same. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean adding `summarize(..., count=n())`?

Comment: You might need to open a new question, this may be more complex than comments can handle. Specifically, I don't understand what you mean by odd and even.

Comment: I am referring to the fact that while computing median, it depends on the number of observations, odd or even.. so median sales may be computed accordingly the logic you have mentioned, but finding the corresponding count value for the same might be difficult due to odd and even number of observations for each flag group